# In IntelliJ IDEA, how to copy non-source assets to output folder during build?

Tags: intellij-idea, build

I have a project in IntelliJ IDEA, inside that a couple of modules and one of my modules has two build configurations. One of them needs to copy a `<projectroot>/tools` folder to its `out/production/<BuildConfigurationName>` folder. Can IDEA somehow automate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can IDEA somehow automate this?

Not directly, no. Ultimately IDEA is an IDE and not a build tool. While it can do a lot during a build, it does not have the ability to copy non-source files to an alternate directory, let alone a dynamically named directory.

If you marked the `tools` directory as a source directory (and none of its contained file types were set in the "Ignore files and folder" setting at the bottom of the "File Types" settings dialog), IDEA would then copy the tools directory to the out directory. But renaming requires a more sophisticated build tool.

Ultimately, the "ideal" or "best practices" solution would be to build your project using a build tool like Maven, Gradle or Ant for which this type of thing would be a snap.

If that is not an option, or for some reason you really want IDEA to do the build, the best thing you could do is to write a simple Ant script to the copy for you. (Or possibly Gradle, I do not have much experience with Gradle yet. Maven could do it, but it'd be a bit cumbersome compared to Ant.) In any Run/Debug configurations, you can define the ant script target to run before or after the IDEA "make" in the `Before Launch` section. (You can set that as a default for any newly created configurations by configuring it in `Defaults` on the left). If you run your build manually, you can assign a shortcut to the ant build and then run it and the make in sequence. Alternatively, you could record a Macro (*Edit > Macros*) to run both in sequence and then (optionally) assign the macro a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Your last paragraph is what I have been looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer above is incorrect. IDEA can do this (without ant/gradle) via the artifacts system (accessed via Build menu or project settings). Any one artifact job copies multiple files/folders/build outputs to a chosen location (optionally jarred) and can be set to automatically run on make.

Artifacts can even be chained, i.e. output from one as input to another.